# Point on surface using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I would like to draw a Point on a surface using `PSTricks` and `pst-solides3d`. What I mean by that is, that the point should look like it is attached onto the surface. That means that the point should not look like a point from different views. My attempt is the following, using `\psProjection`, but it does not work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-10,-10)(10,10)
\psset{
    Decran=50,
    viewpoint=25 25 15 rtp2xyz
}
\psSolid[
    object=octahedron,
    a=2,
    trunc=all,
    trunccoeff=.3333,
    fillcolor=grey!20!,
    name=my_octahedron,
    action=draw*
]
% The following draws a point.
\psSolid[
    object=point,
    definition=solidcentreface,
    args=my_octahedron 10,
    linecolor=red,
    text=X,
    pos=uc
]
% The following is my attempt to plot the same point but looking as it would be attached to the plane of the octahedron.
\psProjection[
    object=point,
    args=0 0,
    linecolor=red,
    pos=uc,
    text=H,
    plan=my_octahedron 10
]
\axesIIID*(1.5,1.45,1.4)(2.7,2,2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated comments: It's not necessary to load other packages than `pst-solides3d`. Also, in general it's a bad idea to have blank lines within a `pspicture` environment.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Why do you think it's a bad idea having blank lines?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I can't remeber the exact reason but a rather long time ago, Herbert told me this, if I'm not mistaken (which I could very well be).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to define the plane first:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}    
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(5,5)
\psset{Decran=50,viewpoint=25 25 15 rtp2xyz}
\psSolid[object=octahedron,a=2,trunc=all,trunccoeff=.3333,
    fillcolor=gray!20!,name=my_octahedron,action=draw*]
% The following draws a point.
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidcentreface,args=my_octahedron 10,
    linecolor=red,text=X,pos=uc]
\psSolid[object=plan,definition=solidface,args=my_octahedron 10,
    action=none,name=my_plan]% dont draw it
\psProjection[object=point,args=0 0,
    linecolor=blue,pos=uc,text=H,plan=my_plan]
\axesIIID*(1.5,1.45,1.4)(2.7,2,2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

for a projected dot use

```
\psProjection[object=cercle,args=0 0 0.05,range=0 360,
    fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,plan=my_plan]
```

[image]

Comment: This draws the point just the way before and only change the text right? I am interested in changing the appearance of the point itself.

Comment: Then you have to draw a filled circle or ellipse. See my edit.