# Projection of circle across two surfaces

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I would like to build on a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163462/point-on-surface-using-pstricks) in which is explained how to project a circle onto a defined plane of an octahedron using pstricks. I would like to know if it is possible to project a circle **across** an edge so that it looks like a sticker that has been put across them.

Here is an example, but I must admit that I am not very talented. I only draw the first half of the "sticker" onto the surface (green). The other is still missing (because it really did not help understanding what I want, at least not in my drawing). I hope this helps understanding what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an image how it should look like?

Comment: @Herbert I added a very raw example. I only have drawn one half of the circle. The other half would have to be drawn on the surface beneath. It looked horrible when I added that so I only draw one half. Hope this helps to understand what I try to achieve.

Comment: show the code please.

Comment: Actually this is not done with pstricks. I just used a vector editing program to add the green half circle (and the full circle with shadows in the middle of the octahedron). The code for the rest is the one in the post I mentioned at the beginning of my question.